# How to install Vagrant on Windows 10 Home without Hyper-V support?

Tags: windows, vagrant, virtualbox, hyper-v

On my Windows 10 Home edition I need to use Vagrant + Oracle VM VirtualBox and during the installation I stuck to an issue: Vagrant needs this Hyper-V Windows feature that is not officially included in Windows 10 Home. According to official Microsoft requirements:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v
Hyper-V is only supported with "Windows 10 Enterprise, Pro, or Education".

Does anyone knows how to use Vagrant and Oracle VM VirtualBox without this feature? If not possible what would you advice: is there another solution (additional software..), or shall I upgrade to Windows 10 Pro?

Answer (score 3):

**Enable Hyper-V in Windows 10 Home**
Follow the steps below to install and enable Hyper-V in Windows 10 Home.

1. Download Hyper-V Enabler from here: [[Hyper-V installer and enabler
   for Windows 10 Home]](https://www.itechtics.com/?dl_id=80)
2. Once downloaded, right-click on the file and select Run as Administrator. This will trigger the installation script. It may take some time to complete the installation. Please let it complete without interruption.
3. Once complete, press Y to continue. The system will restart.
4. You will see the Windows updates screen upon restart.
5. After restarting, you can check if the Hyper-V option is visible in Windows Optional Features. To check, go to Run –> optionalfeatures. You will find Hyper-V and Hyper-V Management tools.